# ionic cordova platform add android is not working and throwing package.json error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

$ ionic cordova platform add android

> cordova.cmd platform add android
> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\XXX\tech\ionic\test\myApp\android\package.json']
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: 'C:/XXX/tech/ionic/test/myApp/android/package.json'

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

$ ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (C:\XXX\tech\nodejslib\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.1.4
@angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.6
@capacitor/core : 2.4.6

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v14.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.14.11
OS     : Windows 10

Desperately need help

Comment: Can you confirm that you are running this command from `C:\XXX\tech\ionic\test\myApp` and not from `C:\XXX\tech\ionic\test\myApp\android` ?

Comment: I am running from C:\XXX\tech\ionic\test\myApp

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` and `config.xml` file please ?